# How to set android:width to 0dp in code?

Tags: android, layout, button

I'm trying to add a button dynamically through code.

But i'm stuck that how to set `android:layout_width` of button to `0dp` through code.

Comment: Why would you set it to "0dp". Any specific reason?

Comment: @Avinazz maybe there is a layout_weight set and the button width needs to be set to 0.

Comment: Even guessed it so. Still waiting for response.

Comment: Yes, i'm setting layout_weight to 1 but unable to set its width to 0dp...

Comment: Can you share your xml snippet. And what result you are looking for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this :

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Import,

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Your button have layoutParams. Get those params, update the width and reapply them:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)myButton.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = 0;
myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
```